How to add before a new line before the (cited on page ...) string in BibLaTeX
I am using \usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex-chicago}
in a book that I am working on. In the generated bibliography sometimes I need to
place the (Cited on page X) on a new line (I do not know how to do it!). This happens when the "(Cited" part is on the of the output line line and created an overfull \hbox. Adding a \break command at the end of the publisher string (i.e., publisher = "Springer\break"), does not solve the problem as the period at the end of the publisher goes to the next line. I tried the following "solution"
\newif\ifmyaddbreak
\myaddbreakfalse
\def\myaddbreakcmd{\ifmyaddbreak\break\myaddbreakfalse\else\fi}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage  = {\myaddbreakcmd{}see p.}, % for single page number
    backrefpages = {\myaddbreakcmd{}see pp.} % for multiple page numbers
}

and I am manually modifying the publisher field as follows
 publisher  =   {Centre for Asia Minor Studies\myaddbreaktrue},

The command is included in the in the bbl file
\list{publisher}{1}{%
{Centre for Asia Minor Studies\myaddbreaktrue}%

}
but the \break command is not executed! I thought that by adding the \global command I would solve the problem,
\def\myaddbreakcmd{\ifmyaddbreak\break{\global\myaddbreakfalse}\else\fi}

but this made things worse:
! Argument of \__text_expand_store:nw has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.61 ...hy[notkeyword=nosample,title=Bibliography]
                                                  

Since I cannot think of anything else right now, I was wondering if anyone could help solve this problem? The following is minimal example that show the problem.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newif\ifmyaddbreak
\myaddbreakfalse
\def\myaddbreakcmd{\ifmyaddbreak\break\myaddbreakfalse\fi}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage  = {\myaddbreakcmd{}See p.}, % for single page number
    backrefpages = {\myaddbreakcmd{}See pp.} % for multiple page numbers
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{alexandris1992,
    author      =   {Alexis Alexandris},
    title       =   {The Greek Minority of Istanbul And Greek-Turkish Relations 1918--1974},
    publisher   =   {Centre for Asia Minor Studies\myaddbreaktrue},
    address     =   {Athens},
    year        =   1992
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=Common]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{UM Typewriter}
Let's us cite the only reference \textcite{alexandris1992}.
\printbibliography[notkeyword=nosample,title=Bibliography]
\end{document}


Please show us a short complete TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I have updated the original question and now it includes a small but complete example  that demonstrates the problem.
